# How can I change current value for identity type primary key column in table in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I had an application and PostgreSQL database with EF Core ORM. There was a table `Cars` and `Id` column had a sequence, where I could change current value for next record. Now I created a new app and moved records from old table to new table in new database. First record has an `Id`=12000 for example.

New records started from 1 and when it reached record with `Id` 12000 I started get following error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Cars"

In new table `Id` column not using sequence anymore, it has an Identity type and I can not change current value in pgAdmin. How can I make my `Id` column change current id value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find out the actual maximum in the table:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM tab;

  max 
════════
 123000
(1 row)
```

Then, set the underlying sequence to a higher value:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER id RESTART 200000;
```